# Search or list unanswered questions by language

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, search

Is it possible to search for unanswered questions AND no other language than language L, for example, only unanswered Java questions? I would like to list all unanswered questions for a given tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can search by unanswered and by tag:

> ```
> [java] is:question answers:0
> ```

The square brackets denote the tag, and the search tips of `is:question` makes sure it's a question, the `answers:0` search tip makes sure there are 0 answers.

The *search results* page has a link in the side bar that expands like this:

[image: advanced search tips]

The link at the bottom points to [this help center page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/searching)